# schedular in windows service

Tags: c#

I had written one windows service in C#.NET which fires on every miniutes... I want to fire a mail to my manager in every month on say xyz date.... this task shld repeted on every month on same date... So can any one tell me how to do this..? I mean to say the block of code which i will write shld get executed on same date of every month...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the windows task scheduler for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a TimeSpan of the number of days/hours/minutes/etc. until the first day of the next month:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.AddDays(
  (DateTime.Now.Day - 1) * -1).AddMonths(1) - DateTime.Now;
```

Use `DateTime.Today` for midnight of the first day of next month.

You can use that to set the interval for a timer.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like the perfect usage for [quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

```
var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

var jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof (MyFooImplementation)); // MyFooImplementation needs to impelement IJob
var trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeMonthlyTrigger("myJobTrigger", 1, 0, 0);
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

more infos on `.MakeMonthlyTrigger` can be found [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic729.html)

otherwise i would got for the windows task scheduler ... the good old-fashioned way :)